# Sites - Is it possible to give access to customers on sites to view opportunities

Tags: force.com-sites

I want to give access to our agents to view  the opportunities under their account,maybe with read and write access. Is this possible? What kind of licensing would be best suited?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Partner Portal users can access the opportunity object and Customer Portal users can't.

Answer (score 0):

Another other way is to use Communities and "mirror" your opportunity object to another object so that it's visible. You'll then need to use a class or triggers to keep the two in sync. You can also do the same with a High Volume Customer Portal license. @ebacho is correct that only a Partner Portal license user can currently access Opportunity directly.